# Minimise $\tan^2 A + \tan^2 B + \tan^2 C$ given a relation

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, optimization, radicals, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Its said that $A,B,C,a$ are real and 
$\sqrt{a^2-4}\tan A + a \tan B + \sqrt{a^2+4} \tan C = 6a$

then minimise $\tan^2 A + \tan^2 B + \tan^2 C$.

I dont know how to proceed, looked like something to do with pythagoras theorem. Nothing more is given, so any hint is welcome.

Comment: Is there something wrong in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $a^2\geq4$ by C-S we obtain:
$$\left(\sqrt{a^2-4}\tan A + a \tan B + \sqrt{a^2+4} \tan C\right)^2\leq$$
$$\leq(a^2-4+a^2+a^2+4)\left(\tan^2 A + \tan^2 B + \tan^2 C\right).$$
Thus, $$\tan^2 A + \tan^2 B + \tan^2 C\geq\frac{36a^2}{3a^2}=12.$$
The equality occurs for $$\left(\sqrt{a^2-4},a,\sqrt{a^2+4}\right)||\left(\tan A,\tan B,\tan C\right),$$
which says that we got a minimal value.

Comment: Thank you! I get the same, dont know why didnt try CS.

Comment: What this means: $\left(\sqrt{a^2-4},a,\sqrt{a^2+4}\right)||\left(\tan A,\tan B,\tan C\right)$

Comment: It means that  there is real  $\lambda$ for which $\sqrt{a^2-4}=\lambda\tan A$,  $a=\lambda\tan B$ and  $\sqrt{a^2+4}=\lambda\tan C$.

Answer (score 2):

We can use [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier). Let
\begin{align}
f(x,y,z)&=\tan^2 x + \tan ^2 y + \tan^2 z,\\
g(x,y,z)&=\sqrt{a^2-4}\tan x+a\tan y + \sqrt{a^2+4}\tan z-6a=0.
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
\nabla f(x,y,z)&=(2\tan x\sec^2 x, 2\tan y\sec^2 y, 2\tan z\sec^2 z),\\
\nabla g(x,y,z)&=(\sqrt{a^2-4}\sec^2 x, a\sec^2 y,\sqrt{a^2+4}\sec^2 z).
\end{align}
Consider the equation $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$, then for a root of the equation $(x^*,y^*,z^*)$,
\begin{cases}\tag 1
2\tan x^*=\lambda\sqrt{a^2-4}\\
2\tan y^*=\lambda a\\
2\tan z^*=\lambda\sqrt{a^2+4}
\end{cases}
Substitute (1) into $g(x,y,z)=0$, then we get $\lambda=4/a$ and
\begin{align}
\tan^2 x^*+\tan^2 y^*+\tan^2 z^* &=\left(\frac{2\sqrt{a^2-4}}{a}\right)^2+\left(\frac{2a}{a}\right)^2+\left(\frac{2\sqrt{a^2+4}}{a}\right)^2\\
&=12.
\end{align}
Thus 12 is what we want to find.